# Attributes and values in suds

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

I have some troubles with complextype in wsdl. Here part of wsdl:

```
<xs:element name="Params" nillable="true">                   
    <xs:complexType>                                                                       
        <xs:sequence>                                                                      
            <xs:element name="Param" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>                             
                    <xs:simpleContent>                       
                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">      
                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:extension>                      
                    </xs:simpleContent>                      
                </xs:complexType>                            
            </xs:element>                                                                  
        </xs:sequence>                                                                     
    </xs:complexType>                                                                      
</xs:element>
```

result fields in SOAP-req must be like:

```
<ns0:Params>
    <ns0:Param ns1:name="name1">val1</ns1:Param>
    <ns0:Param ns1:name="name1">val1</ns1:Param>
</ns0:Params>
```

Suds give me next type:

```
>>> client.factory.create("Payment.Params.Param")  
(Param){  
    _name = ""  
}
```

If I set _name, suds generate XML:

```
<ns0:Params>
    <ns0:Param name="name1"/>
    <ns0:Param name="name2"/>
</ns0:Params>
```

So, I can set attribute name for "Param", but how I can set value?

Comment: If you set `name` (without underscore), what XML do you get?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the 'Param' element without attributes and then use the marshalled plugin to add the 'name' attribute:

```
# disclaimer: not tested!
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin

class MyPlugin(MessagePlugin):
    def marshalled(self, context):
        body = context.envelope.getChild('Body')
        params = body.getChild('fix_this_path').getChild('Params')  
        foo = params[0]
        foo.set('name', 'name1')

client = Client(url, plugins=[MyPlugin()])
...
params = client.factory.create("Payment.Params")
params.param = "val1"
```

more info here: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#MessagePlugin

hope this helps